# How can I popup an edit box (or another modal that can type something) in MFC app when I click a button

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, editbox

I want to popup an edit box or another modal when I click a button. I can type something in this box and when I close it, I will receive the data I've just typed. How can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Most obvious way would be to create a dialog box with one edit control and <kbd>OK</kbd> and <kbd>Cancel</kbd> buttons (you would probably want to alow user to cancel).

Then you provide a method in that dialog to access typed-in value after it was closed.

Comment: You will need to capture a window event when the window is closing, so you can save the contents of the edit control before it's destroyed.